# DynamoDB not returning Scan values

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to query my DynamoDB using **scan**. However, every time I scan it I get the following error:

> "Unable to marshal response: Binary(b`**long_string_of_random_alphanumerics**) is not JSON serializable"

Code:

```
def login(username, password):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('users')
    response = table.scan(
        FilterExpression=Key('username').eq(username)
    )
    items = response["Items"]
    return items
```

Also, the code doesn't give me the error when I encode "username" `bytes(username,"utf-8")`. However, the list that it's returning is empty.

```
Response:
[]
```

I've ran a **query** to check if it's getting any items by primary key and it's returning  1 so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('users')
    response = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('username').eq(username)
    )    
    if response["Count"] == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue today, and found a work around:

```
 response = table.scan(
             FilterExpression = Attr("SS_username").eq(username) & Attr("SS_password").eq(password)
         ) 

    if response["Count"] == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

or any other approach someone could share?

Comment: Please never do `if ⟨condition⟩: return False else: return True`: just `return not ⟨condition⟩` (or use the complementary relational operator in a comparison).